# How to pass 2 data model sources to the SearchField

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'd like to pass data from 2 sources to the Searchfield control through parts as in an example here. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/dfe04650afc046e0802abb1a1a90d2d9

My code:

```
<SearchField
    id="mySFID"
    enableSuggestions="true"
    search="onSelectDiseaseTerm"
    suggest="onSuggestDiseaseTerm1"
    suggestionItems="{
    parts : [
        {path: 'db2>/SOURCE1/'},
        {path: 'db2>/SOURCE2/'}],
    type: 'sap.m.SearchField'}" >
<suggestionItems>
    <SuggestionItem
            text="{db2>DISEASE_TERM}"
            key="{db2>DISEASE_TERM}" />
</suggestionItems>
</SearchField>
```

This is failing with the following trace

```
    Cannot route to target: TypeError: w[b].push is not a function -  
    f   @   sap-ui-core.js:82
    error   @   sap-ui-core.js:82
    (anonymous) @   MyRouter.js?eval:77
    Promise.catch (async)       
    _checkSessionBeforeRoute    @   MyRouter.js?eval:76
    parse   @   MyRouter.js?eval:116
    fnHashChanged   @   Router.js?eval:6
    o.fireEvent @   EventProvider.js?eval:6
    n.fireHashChanged   @   HashChanger.js?eval:6
    execute @   signals.js?eval:93
    dispatch    @   signals.js?eval:384
    Signal.dispatch @   signals.js?eval:187
    (anonymous) @   hasher.js?eval:126
    setHash @   hasher.js?eval:375
    n.setHash   @   HashChanger.js?eval:6
    navTo   @   Router.js?eval:6
    onOpenOrderEditView @   CaseList.controller.js?eval:171
    o.fireEvent @   EventProvider.js?eval:6
    r.fireEvent @   Element.js?eval:6
    (anonymous) @   ManagedObjectMetadata.js?eval:6
    a.<computed>    @   Icon.js?eval:6
    r._handleEvent  @   Element.js?eval:6
    l._handleEvent  @   UIArea.js?eval:6
    dispatch    @   sap-ui-core.js:26
    q.handle    @   sap-ui-core.js:25
```

Comment: Unfortunately `parts` and `type` are not supported in _aggregation binding_: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindAggregation. Either the backend has to support returning both results in one request or you'd have to create two `SearchField` controls separately.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann would it be a workaround if I pre-combine two sources of data somewhere else and pass it as a prop path to the control ?

Comment: Is `db2` an OData model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SearchField](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SearchField)'s `suggestionItems` is an aggregation that takes an array of `sap.m.SuggestionItem` as input. You cannot pass what you're trying to do.

Comment: what if I try to use the formatter before passing data , that was the plan initially

Comment: I don't think (but I could be wrong because I never tried) that formatter is supported on those type of binding. If you need to manipulate data before, you can make the OData.read on your JS, manipulate that, insert them in a JSONModel and than bind your table/list on that JSONModel